# NameError: name 'ftplip' is not defined

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Following is my python code to make a FTP connection

```
upload_ftp.py

import ftplib
ftp = ftplip.FTP()
ftp.connect('ip', 21)
print ftp.getwelcome()
try:
    print "Logging in..."
    ftp.login("username", "password")
except:
    "failed to login"
```

but when i run the code ,i get the following error: NameError:name 'ftplib' is not defined

```
my@my-pc:/var/www$ python upload_ftp.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_ftp.py", line 8, in <module>
    ftp1 = ftplip.FTP()
NameError: name 'ftplip' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: yup....i m getting the error in ftplib

Comment: you should ftplib.FTP() over ftplip.FTP()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: you writing `ftplip.FTP()` but it is `ftplib.FTP()` (lip with p vs lib with b).

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling error in your variable name. So Python thinks you are using an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
```

Return a new instance of the FTP class.